# How to access a variable value from one class to another class?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following

First class;

```
Public Class Settings

    Dim goal_x As Integer

    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button.Click
        goal_x = Convert.ToInt32(goal_x_set.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to access this goal_x integer variable in a different class, in another word, i want the variable value to calculate a percentage in a different class something slimier to this

In second class

```
Public Class shift_1
Private Sub button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button11.Click
        shft1_gage.Value = (Parameter Value from Class 1{goal_1})*5645/38745*100
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Research *Properties* if you want your class to expose something to other actors.  it's a pretty basic concept of OOP

Comment: Also read up on _Access Levels_ and _Access Modifiers_: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels

Comment: just put `Public goal_x as Integer` and use it as `Settings.goal_x` in another place where you want

Answer (score 1):

The code for your `Settings` class is just a class definition. It describes how *instances* of that class will work. In order to use the class, you need to create an `instance` of the class, and store a `reference` to that instance somewhere that will be accessible to instances of your `shift_1` class.

This is 101-level stuff, and the fact that the Settings class is also a form doesn't change this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the variable from another Form Like This :

Form 1

```
Public Class Form1
Public x = 5
End Class
```

Form 2

```
Public Class Form2
Dim a As Integer
a = Form1.x
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want your class variable to be access by another class, you can put the
public statement to your variable or in your class you create the property to get and set